# Why can't this 8K video recorded with an Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra be viewed as 8K in YouTube?

Tags: video, youtube, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I recorded an 8K video with
a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13:

[image]

I uploaded it to YouTube using the YouTube Android application. YouTube offers to view it in 4K but not 8K:

[image]

Why?

This issue happened with the 5 videos I recorded in 8K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reddit user [thedankonion1](https://www.reddit.com/user/thedankonion1) [mentioned](https://redd.it/17fx6b9) that the YouTube Android application can only see up to 4K. It doesn't allow uses to view videos in 5K or 8K. I had checked YouTube via a computer too, but I got mislead by `https://studio.youtube.com/video/[video id]/edit`, which only indicates 4k and not 8k:

[image]

However, looking at the actual video via `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[video ID]` with a computer, I do see the 8k option. So that explains the situation.

Comment: Also related on Reddit: [Watch 4K or 8K on mobile YouTube app?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Galaxy_S20/comments/fp15kr/watch_4k_or_8k_on_mobile_youtube_app/)